# Xojo detect input from 2 inputs with interrupts. (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, xojo

I have a raspberry pi 3 running a program made in Xojo.

My goal is to have two flow sensors which display the amount of water that flows though each sensor on the screen.

I have a program that works for one flow sensor, it uses the GPIO library and a custom module called 'InterruptModule'.  I followed a tutorial to make this program.

Tutorial: https://einhugur.com/blog/index.php/xojo-gpio/connecting-button-with-gpio-and-using-interupts/#comment-14

This program works successfully for both flow sensors, but only one at a time.  I.e if I change the input pin and run the program again it works.

HOWEVER, when I try combine the two it responds can't differentiate between the two inputs.

I have tried with two GPIO modules and two custom 'InterruptModule' modules but it still counts the inputs under whichever sensor is defined first.

See my attempt here.

[Screenshot of Xojo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfuF4.png)

Comment: Not sure, but in the "Start flood" section you call SetupGPIO a second time. Could that be resetting and clearing the first input you configured?

Answer (score 0):

One way to differentiate between the two interrupts is to create two separate callback method.

Example:

```
Const kPin = 14
If GPIO.WiringPiISR(kPin, GPIO.EDGE_RISING, Addressof InteruptModule.ButtonDownInterupt1) = -1 then
MsgBox "Could not register for Interupt1 on kPin14"
End If

Const kPin = 18
If GPIO.WiringPiISR(kPin, GPIO.EDGE_RISING, Addressof InteruptModule.ButtonDownInterupt2) = -1 then
MsgBox "Could not register for Interupt2 on kPin18"
End If
```

In this example, each pin interruption would have its own callback method with different code to work with each pin.